# How to get attributes with the same column name after joins (Symfony framework with Propel)?

Tags: php, join, symfony1, propel

I have two tables:

Table1:

- id
- attr1
- fk1(Table2)
- fk2(Table2)

Table2:

- id
- name

I want to join Table1 with Table2 on fk1 and fk2. How can I do this two joins and after that get both name attributes from Table2.
I would like to do it with Table1Query rather than Table1Peer.

Comment: what do you exactly want to obtain with the query?

Comment: I want to display Table1 objects in table. Problem is that I'm getting fk1 and fk1 in my table (no names). After that join I will have access to the name attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my answer to this question: [Naming Generated Functions in Propel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091531/naming-generated-functions-in-propel/8683885#8683885)

Since you have two foreign keys that point to the same table, you need to utilize the "phpName" attribute on the "foreign-key" element.